# Get authoryear citation using Natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I would like to have a citation to give the author(s)'s abbreviated name(s) and the year of publication of the citation, in other words if the citation is by Alex Hock, Tom Geek in 2009 then the cited text should look like :

`[HG09]` or `[HG'09]`

How do I get this? I am using *natbib* with *authoryear, square, numbers* options and what I get is `Hock and Geek [2009]`. Is this possible using natbib or should I have to use some other package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result using the `numbers` option, i.e., `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and the `alpha.bst` bib style. i.e., `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`.